# Dynamics CRM 2011 Online - how do you read all products for an order?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have the following code...

```js
var oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc

var oDataSelect = "/SalesOrderSet?" +
    "&$filter=(guid'" + id + "')" + 
    "&$expand=order_details"
```

My question is this... Does the id of an entity include the full url or just the guid? If it's the full url I would only need...

```js
var oDataSelect = id + "&$expand=order_details"
```

and not the oDataPath, correct?

Comment: Hey Gary, if you're happy with the answers, would you mind marking one an answer.  If none is the answer you need, can you clarify your open question in the comment? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative. You need to insert the id as a guid. You can see this for yourself if you navigate to:

> Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/SalesOrderSet"

If you do this in a browser, you may need to right click and View Source.

Answer (score -1):

If you write your client in js then try JayData. Your query would be something like:

```
crm.SalesRecords.filter('it.id==1').include('order_details').toArray()
```